# Filestack how to Document Conversion

Tags: document, filepicker

i try several time to convert a text document to a pdf. But it didnt work.
i get 
"FPError 142: The FPFile could not be converted with the requested parameters. For help, see https://developers.filepicker.io/answers/jsErrors/142"
i use

```
filepicker.convert({
    url: "SOMEFILE",
    mimetype: 'text/*',
  },
  {
    output: "format:pdf,pageformat:A4:legal",
  },
  function(Blob){
    console.log(replaceHtmlChars(JSON.stringify(Blob)));
  },
  function(FPError){
    console.log(FPError.toString());
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The filepicker.convert() method does not support document conversions.

Only basic image conversions.

For document conversions, we have our REST API.

https://www.filestack.com/docs/document-transformations

You could capture the file handle after an upload and then build our processing engine URLs with javascript:

```
$('#fpButton').click(function() {
  filepicker.setKey("your_API_KEY");
  filepicker.pick({
      services: ['COMPUTER'],
      mimetypes: ['application/pdf']
    },
    function(Blob) {
      console.log(Blob.url);
      addLink(Blob);
      addLink2(Blob);
      addLink3(Blob);
    }
  );
});

function addLink(data) {
  $("#results")
    .append(
      '<a target="_blank" href="' +
      data.url + '">' + data.filename + '</a>'
    );
}

function addLink2(data) {
  $("#results2").append('<img target="_blank" src="' +
    'https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:jpg/resize=w:200/' + data.url.substr(data.url.lastIndexOf("/")+1) + '">'
  );
}

function addLink3(data) {
  $('#results3').load('https://process.filestackapi.com/output=docinfo:true/' + data.url.substr(data.url.lastIndexOf("/")+1) + '');
}
```

Here is an example that will let you upload a PDF and then convert that PDF into an image for a preview. The same technique could be used to turn a TXT file to a PDF.

https://jsfiddle.net/amione/hbbpamva/